# Most efficient way to implement Dashboard UI pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, dashboard, ui-design, ui-patterns

I want to do the [Dashboard pattern](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/01/implementing-dashboard-and-action-bar.html). I currently do this for each home button:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="onHomeButtonClicked"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The reason I wrap my button inside a FrameLayout is I want to:

- Maximize the clickable area
- Make the icon and text properly
  centered.

I tried doing this in the past but gave up because I couldn't figure out a screensize-independent way of centering the text and icon:

```
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:onClick="onHomeButtonClicked"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_PUT_IN_HERE" />
```

My question: Is it possible to do all these:

1. Not wrap the Button inside other
   layout (using only 1 view per
   button)
2. Maximize the clickable area
3. Properly center the icon and text in
   a screensize-independent way

Many thanks.

Comment: After checking the link you provided, is there a reason not to go with GridView for creating Dashboard pattern? Or is it how you're populating these layouts to display anyway?

Comment: Is it possible to declare the content of `GridView` in the XML layout, or I have to populate them in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that I use to build a dashboard programmatically:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v = (TextView) convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        v = new TextView(DashboardActivity.this);
        v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
    v.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,
        mIcons[position].drawableId, 0, 0);
    v.setText(mIcons[position].labelId);

    return v;
}
```

You could instead use android:drawableTop in an XML file if you could build the dashboard beforehand.